# datastax enterprise 5.0.2 spark count error

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have built a analytic cluster which is datastax 5.0.2 to test spark. I also wrote simple code which gives table count.

First of all, I run my code at analytic cluster using dse spark-submit jarfile. I test my code in two way. one way is to get row count of table which is in my production cluster, other one is to get row count of table which is in my fresh analytic cluster.

When I try to get row count of table which is in my production cluster is OK. But when i try to get row count of table which is in my test cluster, i get error. The error message doesnt mean to me since i am new the subject. I tried to add snappy jar file also.

Can anyboydy help me?

```
    WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:06,126 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, 46.166.139.66): java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExcept$
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1212)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1205)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version$lzycompute(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:170)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:145)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:169)
        ... 23 more

ERROR 2016-09-08 11:11:06,190 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 17$
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1212)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1205)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version$lzycompute(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:169)
        ... 23 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
        at mapreducer.App.main(App.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1212)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1205)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version$lzycompute(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:169)
        ... 23 more
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:06,294 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 46.166.187.187): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:06,662 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 46.166.139.74): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:06,787 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 46.166.139.72): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:06,961 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 46.166.139.71): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:08,039 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 46.166.139.72): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:08,099 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 46.166.139.73): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:08,039 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 46.166.139.72): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:08,099 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 46.166.139.73): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
WARN  2016-09-08 11:11:08,342 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 46.166.139.71): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
```

Comment: It seems that there exist duplicate jars with different version in your classpath.

Comment: @lege I solved this problem but. I used lz4 compression not snappy in SparkConf.